# Renaming all files on the form *.extension.{index} to *_{index}.extension

Tags: windows, shell-script

This question is related to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378194/adding-a-postfix-when-downloading-files-using-curl-if-a-file-by-that-name-alread) question over at Unix & Linux SE.

I have a bunch of files with filenames on the form *.pdf.{index} (filenames are due to wget) that I'd like to rename to *_{index}.pdf. In other words: file.pdf.1 should be renamed to file_1.pdf, and so on.

I'm familiar with (Ba)sh shell scripting, but not Windows shell scripts. I tried starting with

```
for %%f in (*.pdf.?) do (
    echo %%f
    (whatever)
)
```

but this seems to match even files like "test.pdf" that don't have anything after the extension and I can't figure out how to extract the integer part separately. Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I have no windows but it looks not that complicated to iterate a directory, replace string and rename files. You can find all in one command [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item) in "Example 4", I guess. And the regular expression for replacing pattern should be the same like for Linux, so as you said you should know it.

Comment: That's for PowerShell, which I can't/won't use in this scenario.